# android application memory storage

Tags: android

i have made application in which Homesceen stored username and password than redirect on second page .when i close this application or power off device than again click on application icon than i want to redirect on second page . so what can i do for doing this ? can we get power off functionality or anything else ? how to stored variable in memory of this application ?

Answer (score 0):

You could used [**Shared Preferences**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to store your login and password :

> The `SharedPreferences` class provides
>   a general framework that allows you to
>   save and retrieve persistent key-value
>   pairs of primitive data types. 
> You
>   can use `SharedPreferences` to save
>   any primitive data: booleans, floats,
>   ints, longs, and strings. 
> This
>   data will persist across user sessions
>   (even if your application is killed).

Comment: Thanx alot Martin .. i m trying this. i hope it will he;p me .

Comment: hi Martin . i want to only stored one Boolean value . so how can i manage this?